# GTFS - Find all trips of a single day

Tags: python, pandas, gtfs

I need to filter all trips per region per day. I'm using pandas and python to do so

So I've built a dataframe that links each route_id to the region that route covers(if more than one region it's "National").  And then I need to find out the number of trips per departement per day.

The dataframe I built linking each route_id to its region (departement) is called `stops_scope`.
What I'm using :

```
SELECT count(route_id), dep FROM stops_scope 
GROUP_BY dep
WHERE route_id IN (
    SELECT route_id FROM trips WHERE service_id IN (
        SELECT service_id FROM calendar_dates WHERE date == "20200406"
    )
)
```

To obtain this result for every day I loop through all days inside calendar_dates.

Of course I'm not using the SQL but the pandas equivalent. I feel like I'm missing something, because this doesn't work.

Comment: Did you checked `calendar` table ? service_id can be referenced in `calendar` and/or `calendar_dates`.

Comment: Yes I did use both although I missed it at first.